# after changing product image programatically, old image remains in catalog view

Tags: magento-1.9

after changing main product image to custom proramatically,

```
            Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_action')->updateAttributes(array($this->_product_id),
                                     array('image'=>$value['file']), 0);
```

still on catalog view old image remains (in the product view everything is OK), how to fix it ?
thanks !

ps
caching is disabled

Answer (score 0):

It's really not clear what you mean. If you mean on a product list page the image is now different to the image on the product view page, then the product list is probably using `thumbnail` or `small_image`. You could see what images the products has set if you edit it in the admin section.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try cleaning the catalog image cache? Product images used in the template are usually resized and copied to a cache directory. I think this is always on.
If you look at the image source path it will look like this:

```
http://www.shop.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/300x/4239402349023ggd0g9834/i/m/image_name.jpg
```

This cache is cleaned in **System->Cache Management->Flush Catalog Images Cache**